# How To Detect If No Content On Next Page?

Tags: php, sql, hyperlink, pagination, limit

I am making a simple pagination system which all you need to do is click more to load the next content. The only issue is when they get to the end of the line they can still click more. This leads them to error page so How could I detect that there is no SQL content on the next page?

Here's what I have so far:

```
if(($fetch_data_value) && ($check_user_exists_num_rows==1)) {
  $block_user_from_post_query = $db->query("INSERT INTO spud_groups_posts_blocked (user_blocked,pid,block_type) VALUES ('$fetch_data_value','$sanitize_pid_being_posted','post')");
}

$add_page_num = $page+1;
$minus_page_num = $page-1;
echo "<a href='?gname=$get_group_url1&page=$add_page_num&scroll=noset'> More </a>";
```

Comment: just get the total number of pages, that would be the end of it

Comment: Could you show me an example please

Comment: how many entries does your paging load for each page? 5? 10?

Comment: each page loads 10 posts so that be 10 posts per page ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get how many pages do you have. Total number of rows divided by the number of how many entries you load for each page and then round it by its ceiling.

`10` is an example. 10 entries loads after clicking `More`:

```
SELECT CEIL(COUNT(id) / 10) AS total_pages FROM table_name
```

Query it, then get the results, then process it in PHP.

```
// pseudo code
$total_pages = // query it and get the result number
$add_page_num = $page+1;

if($add_page_num < $total_pages) {
    echo "<a href='?gname=$get_group_url1&page=$add_page_num&scroll=noset'> More </a>";
}
```

Now if its still less than the total pages you'll have the `More` link. It it does not then it will not appear anymore.

Comment: Thanks ;)
I try this and get back to you with in 10 minutes

Comment: it's close but didn't work think im on the right track sort of and thanks so far ;)

Comment: got it working by adding $add_numpage<= $totalpages
Thanks for getting me on the right track :D
Answered Accepted

Comment: no problem ;) I would of plused one but need more rep